# How to solve Flurry Error code -104 No render time ad received for this space?

Tags: ios

> errorDescription Error Domain=FlurryAds Code=104 "FlurryAds: No render
>   time ad received for this space."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=FlurryAds: No render time ad received
>   for this space.}

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and asked on Github. Here is a dev answer:

> The error code 104 is shown when there are no ads available for the ad space at the current time and location. It should just be a fill-rate issue and is heavily dependent on the ad demand available in your location.
>   If you have concerns with the fill-rate in your app, please contact support@flurry.com.

[See full discussion](https://github.com/flurry/ios-AdIntegrationSamples/issues/6)